# Why is this Perl foreach loop only executing only once?

Tags: perl

I am trying to copy the content of three separate `.vect` files into one. I want to do this for all 5,000 files in the `$fromdir` directory.

When I run this program it generates just a single modified `.vect` file in the output directory. If I include the `close(DATA)` calls after individual `while` loops inside the `foreach` loop, I get the same behavior: a single output file in the output directory instead of the wanted 5,000 files.

I have done some reading, and at first thought I may not be opening the files. But if I `print($vectfile)` in the `foreach` loop every file name in the directory is printed.

My second thought was that it was how I was closing the files, but
I get the same behavior whether
I close the file handles inside or outside the `foreach` loop.

My final thought was maybe I don't have write permission to the file or directory, but I don't know how to change this.

How can I get this loop to run all 5,000 times and not just once?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $dir = "D:\\Downloads";

# And M3.1 and P3.1
my $subfolder = "A0.1";

my $fromdir = $dir . "\\" . $subfolder;

my @files = <$fromdir/*vect>;

# Top of file
my $readfiletop = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\MoreKnotVis\\ScriptsForAdditionalDataSets\\VectFileHeader.vect";

# Bottom of file
my $readfilebottom = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\MoreKnotVis\\ScriptsForAdditionalDataSets\\VectFileCloser.vect";


foreach my $vectfile ( @files ) {

    say("$vectfile");

    my $count        = 0;
    my $readfilebody = $vectfile;
    my $out_file     = "D:\\Downloads\\ColorsA0.1\\" . "$count" . ".vect";

    $count++;

    # open top part of each file
    open(DATA1, "<", $readfiletop) or die "Can't open '$readfiletop': $!";

    # open bottom part of each file
    open(DATA3, "<",  $readfilebottom) or die "Can't open '$readfilebottom': $!";

    # open a file to read
    open(DATA2, "<", $vectfile) or die "Can't open '$vectfile': $!";

    # open a file to write to
    open(DATA4, ">" ,$out_file) or die "Can't open '$out_file': $!";

    # Copy data from VectFileTop file to another.
    while ( <DATA1> ) {
        print DATA4 $_; 
    }

    # Copy the data from VectFileBody to another.
    while ( <DATA2> ) {
        print DATA4 $_, $_ if 8..12;
    }


    # Copy the data from VectFileBottom to another.
    while ( <DATA3> ) {
        print DATA4 $_;
    }    
}

close( DATA1 );
close( DATA2 );
close( DATA3 );
close( DATA4 );

print("quit\n");
```

Comment: `print DATA4 $_, $_ if 8..12;` what is this `8..12`?

Comment: Why the double semicolons `;;`?

Comment: The language isn't called PERL, just like your name isn't MATT.

Comment: someone's attitude is basically depends upon the grade. Is it right @Borodin?

Comment: @ssr1012: I don't know what you mean by that. Grade of what?

Comment: That means of `knowledge`. In my passport firstname and surname in full caps only.

Comment: @ssr1012: I don't see how "grade" (of anything) has anything to do with "knowledge". Are you saying that I shouldn't insist on a correct spelling of "Perl"? Your passport is probably handwritten, and the name is written in BLOCK CAPITALS to ensure that it is readable. Readability has no bearing on computer text.

Comment: Your `for` loop is executing the correct number of times (as your `print()` statement shows you. But you are giving each file the same name. You should not reset `$count` to 0 on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Borodin: `Perl` is not related to any other names *just like your name isn't MATT* I am wonder about this comment. (Might be unrelated parable) That's why I said.

Comment: @ssr1012: *"Perl is not related to any other names"* What do you mean? It's just a *proper noun* and is no different from names such as *Eiffel Tower* or *Matthew Ward*. I also don't know what you mean by an *"unrelated parable"*.

Answer (score 3):

You construct the output file name including `$count` in it.

But note what you do with this variable:

- initially, but **inside the loop** you set it to 0,
- the output file name is constructed with `0` in it,
- then you increment it, but this has no effect, because this variable
  is again set to 0 in the next execution of the loop..

The effect is that:

- the loop executes the required numer of times,
- but the output file name **every time** contains 0 as the "number",
  so you keep overwriting **the same file** with a new content.

Move `my $count = 0;` instruction **before the loop** and everything
should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be clinging to a specific form of code in fear of everything falling apart if you change a single thing. I recommend that you dare to stray a little more from the formula so that the code is more concise and readable

The problem is that you reset your `$count` to zero before processing each input file, so all the output files have the same name and overwrite one another. The remaining output file contains only the data from the *last* input file

Here's a refactoring of your code. I can't guarantee that it will run correctly but it looks right and does compile

- I've added `use autodie` to avoid having to check the status of every IO operation
- I've used the same lexical file handle `$fh` for all the input file. Opening another file on a file handle that is already open will close it first, and a lexical file handle will be closed by perl when it goes out of scope at the end of the block
- I've used a `while` loop to iterate over the input file names instead of reading the whole list into an array which unnecessarily uses an additional variable `@files` and wastes space
- I've used forward slashes instead of backslashes in all the file paths. This is fine in library calls on Windows: it is only a problem if they appear in command line input

I hope you'll agree that this form is more readable. I think you would have stood a much better chance of finding the problem if your code were in this form

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw/ say /;

my $indir     = 'D:/Downloads';
my $subdir    = 'A0.1';                    # And M3.1 and P3.1
my $extrasdir = 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/MoreKnotVis/ScriptsForAdditionalDataSets';

my $outdir     = "$indir/Colors$subdir";
my $topfile    = "$extrasdir/VectFileHeader.vect";
my $bottomfile = "$extrasdir/VectFileCloser.vect";

my $filenum;

while ( my $vectfile = glob "$indir/$subdir/*.vect" ) {

    say qq/Processing "$vectfile"/;

    $filenum++;

    open my $outfh, '>', "$outdir/$filenum.vect";

    my $fh;

    open $fh, '<', $topfile;
    print { $outfh } $_ while <$fh>;

    open $fh, '<', $vectfile;
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        print { $outfh } $_, $_ if 8..12;
    }

    open $fh, '<', $bottomfile;
    print { $outfh } $_ while <$fh>;
}

say 'DONE';
```